# How can I hide an image on the amp version of my WordPress website?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, amp-html

You'll notice on my blog post here: http://www.profitanywhereblog.com/twitter-following/ I have a right aligned image at the top of the post. I'd like to hide that image but only on the amp version of my website.

I read [here](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/guides/responsive_amp) that any amp customizations should be enclosed in style tags like this:

```css
<style amp-custom>
img.alpha {
    display: none;
}
</style>
```

(I gave the image I want to hide the class "alpha" since I know none of my other website images have that class).

I put this code in the head section of website using this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/header-and-footer-scripts-inserter/

It made my image disappear in the non-amp version but the image remained in the amp version of my site.

I'd appreciate some help as I'm a blogger, not a coder.

Comment: By the way, I have since removed that code from the head of my website.

Answer (score 0):

Try this css to hide images form the amp page

```
amp-img {
  display:none;
}
```

Comment: can you add amp rendered html code here if possible?

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<style amp-custom>
amp-img.alpha.alignright {
    display: none;
}
</style>
```

You just needed a stronger selector than the ones in the amp css.

Comment: Thanks, Diogo. Unfortunately, that code didn't change anything. But I've left it in the head in case you can inspect element and see if there's a conflict.